# getting error [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error

Tags: lightning-web-components, integration, platform-event, subscriber, pubsublwc

[image]

```js
    import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
    import { subscribe, unsubscribe, onError } from 'lightning/empApi';
    import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
    
    export default class SubscribeToPlatformEvent extends LightningElement {
        @track showMessage = false;
        @track message = '';
        channelName = '/event/Test_Services__e';
    
        connectedCallback() {
            onError(error => {
                console.error('EMP API error: ', JSON.stringify(error));
            });
        }
    
        subscribeToPlatformEvent() {
            try {
                // Callback invoked whenever a new event message is received
                const messageCallback = response => {
                    try {
                        const agentNumber = response.data.payload.Agent_Number__c;
                        const opportunity  = response.data.payload.Opportunity_Link__c;
    
                        // Display a toast message for every incoming call
                        const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Incoming Call',
                            message: `Incoming call from ${agentNumber}
                                        For Opportunity${opportunity}`,
                            variant: 'info',
                        });
                        this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error('Error handling message: ', JSON.stringify(error));
                    }
                };
    
                // Subscribe to the Platform Event
                subscribe(this.channelName, -1, messageCallback).then(response => {
                    console.log('Successfully subscribed to: ', JSON.stringify(response));
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error subscribing to platform event: ', JSON.stringify(error));
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error subscribing to platform event: ', JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        }
    
        // Unsubscribe when the component is destroyed
        disconnectedCallback() {
            try {
                unsubscribe(this.channelName);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error unsubscribing from platform event: ', JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
    <!--HTML-->
    
    <template>
        <lightning-card title="Incoming Call">
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <!-- Remove "utility:" prefix from icon-name -->
                <lightning-icon icon-name="down" size="small"></lightning-icon>
                <lightning-button label="Subscribe" onclick={subscribeToPlatformEvent}></lightning-button>
                <div if:true={showMessage}>
                    <p>{message}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </lightning-card>
    </template>
```